# Select everything to the right of a specific character and delete it from column

Tags: vba, excel

My column S needs to only contain one word, however, on import it usually has about three words separated by commas. I would like to only keep the first word in the cell.

For example, my S1 column has something like "x, y, z" and I would like to make S1 only say x. So basically, I am trying to remove everything to the right of the first comma in the cell. I have tried to use Replace, but that isn't working. Is there a simpler way to do this?

My (failing) macro right now:

```
For i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 19) = "," Then Columns("S:i").Select
        Selection.Replace What:=Trim(Right(ActiveCell.Value, 25), InStr(ActiveCell.Value, ",") - 1), Replacement:=""
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @pnuts I was able to complete this task. I was unaware that wildcards could be used in Replace. This is my (working) macro:

```
Columns("S:S").Replace What:=",*", Replacement:=""
```

Comment: @pnuts that's much better! I guess after just staring at it for so long, my brain was telling me the loop was needed :p. Editing the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a `Split` function.

It works like this:

```
Dim str As String: str = "x, y, z"

Debug.Print Split(str, ",")(0)
```

Result is `x`

The important parameters for `Split` are `string` and `delimiter`, the number after the function specifies the occurence. So if you wanted to select `y`, you would put 1 there etc. In that case, you would probably include the space in the delimiter so you would not need to trim the result further.

Comment: @pnuts You are right, what you are suggesting is much better. I didn't know that you can use wildcards in 'Replace'. I'm glad I know that now, thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use left with Instr to give you all the characters before the first comma.

```
ActiveCell = Left(ActiveCell,Instr(ActiveCell,",")-1)
```

Comment: Run-Time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument. Any idea why?

Comment: If you use it on a cell with no comma. You can use an if to qualify.